# calling a .so shared library object from php

Tags: php, shared-libraries

I have a statically linked .so that I'm supposed to be able to call a function from, and its first argument is the memory address of the data to be processed. I have a sample caller written in Pascal, but what I'd like to know is, is it possible to call this library function from PHP? If so, how?
Note: this .so was not written as a PHP extension

Comment: You don't "call a library". You call functions in a library.

Comment: Ok, added some function terminology for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library I wanted to use was not written as a PHP extension, I had to write a wrapper extension in C, creating a PHP method which takes PHP arguments and calls the library function using the arguments after they are transformed (e.g. using a pointer for the memory address).

Comment: Would be nice to see the Example ?

Answer (score 0):

To load a PHP extension at runtime, you use the [dl()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) function.

```
if (!extension_loaded('myextension')) {
   dl('myextension.so');
}
```

You should then be able to use your objects/functions from within that library.

Another thing to remember is the **enable_dl** directive in your php.ini needs to be enabled.

Comment: Doesn't the .so have to meet certain requirements to be a php extension? This .so was not written as one

Comment: @Reese, there's nothing about it in the documentation. Just try to load it an see if it works.

Comment: You may have to modify the .so to work as a PHP Extension. http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

Comment: I don't have access to the source used to compile the .so. Are you saying that the **only** way to use a function in a .so in PHP is to compile it as a PHP extension?